# Preserve playback position in VLC between multiple computers

Tags: vlc-media-player

I'm storing my video files on a network server via Samba (network share) and playing them on multiple computers.

Is there a way to preserve playback position in VLC in order to continue playing from where I left? Even if I'm accessing the same file using another computer or operating system (dual boot).

I don't mind storing some metafile along with video.

Comment: no, it doesn't appear that the VLC command line options include the ability to start a stream at an arbitrary time offset (just by "chapter"), so probably not. That said there are only about a thousand options, so perhaps I missed one here: https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help

Comment: Command line option Frank was referring to is --start-time. However, that doesn't, by itself, answer the question though, as there still needs to be some mechanism to constantly or on exit store the time to start from on the next launch, and something that reads that stored start time and launches vlc with the appropriate option argument.

Answer (score 0):

For lack of any better solution, you may be able to cook up something yourself to keep this in sync.

The "restart where playback left off" function seems to be part of the particular user interface. The QT interface saves its own configuration file, `vlc-qt-interface.ini`, in [the same location as the VLC configuration file](https://www.videolan.org/support/faq.html#Config) (for instance on Windows, in `%appdata%\vlc`).

The `vlc-qt-interface.ini` file has recently accessed media in the `[RecentsMRL]` section; it seems like the `list` setting has a comma-separated list of URLs starting with the most recent, and the corresponding most recent playback positions in milliseconds for those files are in the same order in `times`.

If all of your systems run a similar version of VLC and access the media the same way (so that they will end up with the same URL for the same piece of media) it would be enough to keep this file in sync between systems.